# Cannot find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python-3.x, pip, easy-install

***NOTE:*** *I have seen multiple answers to no avail, so please look at the solution and my failed solutions list before showing as duplicate.*

Hey,

So I got a new computer (Old Windows w/ Python 3.4), so I installed Python 3.5 on my new one. I started to install modules until I came across an error like this:

```
C:\Users\Samuel>pip install noise
Collecting noise
  Using cached noise-1.2.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: noise
  Running setup.py install for noise
    Complete output from command "c:\program files\python 3.5\python.exe" -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Samuel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-e9dlwpm2\\noise\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-7tgvnyfe-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\noise
    copying perlin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\noise
    copying setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\noise
    copying shader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\noise
    copying shader_noise.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\noise
    copying test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\noise
    copying __init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\noise
    running build_ext
    building 'noise._simplex' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files\python 3.5\python.exe" -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Samuel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-e9dlwpm2\\noise\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-7tgvnyfe-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-e9dlwpm2\noise
```

I tried to use `easy_install` as a substitute, but that came with 1) an access denied error (Overcome w/ admin privelages) and 2) Not being able to find vcvarsall.bat

Because of this, I installed *Visual Studio 2015* and *Visual C++ 2008*.
No difference.

I added the path to `vcvarsall.bat` to the PATH.
No difference.

I added the path to `vcvarsall.bat` to `VS100COMNTOOLS`, `VS140COMNTOOLS` and `VS90COMNTOOLS`.
No difference.

Running `pip` and `easy_install` again w/ admin permission, wearing my lucky socks.
No difference.

Installed and ran Miniconda as suggested by one of the Stack Overflow answers.
Didn't find a single package I needed. Turns out it's not looking for PyPI anyway.

I have no idea how to solve this. Do I need to revert to Python 3.4?

**SPECS**

- Windows 10 x86 64-bit
- Python 3.5
- VS 2015, VC++ 2008 installed

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong C++: VC++ 2008 is for Python before 3.3.

The VC++ 2015 that you need comes when you install Visual Studio 2015 **but** you need to explicitly specify the C++ (check the box) for the C++ (2015) in the custom installation options.  Try changing that via a re-installation.

Just tried it:

- Windows 10 x86 64-bit
- Python 3.5
- VS 2015 **But with the Visual C++ install option checked**

Then `pip install noise` worked fine.